# Import and run tizk code in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

If I have an org-mode file where I want to embed a TikZ rendering at a certain place, I've found the simplest is just to throw something like this in where you want it, i.e., no code block necessary:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
    \input{x2vxlogx.tikz}
    %\caption{A graph}
    %\label{fig:graph}
\end{figure}
```

Works just fine. But in order to have it work, I've had to change my file headers, i.e., before I had

```
# this makes MathJax work, but the tex code import not
#+OPTIONS: tex:t
```

versus

```
# This makes MathJax not work, but the tex code import work
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
```

Is there anyway to get both, i.e., have my math done by MathJax *and* my tikz file import work too? I could leave it with `#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick`, but then my math formulae are done as little pngs, which line up poorly on the page.